# How to enumerate HTTP listeners from a Java EE web app

Tags: web-applications, ssl, jakarta-ee, https

I have a web app with a web-based configuration UI. If the user accesses via HTTP, I want to alert the user that they should really use HTTPS and give them a link to click on to get to the HTTPS-prefixed URL.

Now, this is pretty straightforward if we're on the default ports, but often, we're not - for example, HTTP might be on 8080, with HTTPS on 8181. I can have some heuristics for figuring out which port to use, e.g. 80->443, 8080->8181, but is there any way to get a list of ports and protocols back from the web container? Ideally Java EE standard, but even container-specific would be a start...

EDIT - one clarification - this is for an 'off-the-shelf' application ([OpenSSO](http://opensso.org/)), so I'd really like to be able to (a) give the user the choice to go ahead and use an insecure port if they *really* want to (e.g. they're deploying on their laptop on some container without a secure port) and (b) not make the user edit server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer them automatically to https by using configuration only.

in your web.xml:

```
<user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>
    CONFIDENTIAL
  </transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

and in your server.xml in the HTTPConnector:

```
redirectPort="YOUR_SSL_PORT"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a load balancer, usually it can be configured to perform that kind of  redirect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you can query the [ServletRequest getProtocol](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getProtocol()) to see if the connection is coming in as HTTP or HTTPS and what version.  As a bonus you can get which port.

Make the decision and redirect (or forward) to the app specified port.

For further clarification to answered; [Enabling HTTPS communication support](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid92_gci1236977,00.html)